# How to make a html div vertically scrollable after it's height reaches 100% height of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollview

I have a a div on my page, and I also have a button, that when pressed, adds a new `<p>` element in that `<div>`. If I keep pressing the button the height of the div will exceed the height of the actual page, and I'd have to scroll the page in order to see the last paragraph, and then scroll back up in order to press the button again. I want the div to become vertically scrollable after it reaches the height of the page. This is the CSS that I used for the div:

```
div#messages{
width: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding:20px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But the `overflow-y:auto;` property doesn't seem to work?

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the desired effect?

Thanks.

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/pm5wkgv4/

Comment: Add max-height to div#messages, and when it reaches that max-height you'll get scrolling.

Comment: Hey @aCodingN00b set up a http://jsFiddle.net for this question and it'll get solved in a couple of min

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pm5wkgv4/ Here, thanks.

Comment: Use `max-height: 100%;` ? http://jsfiddle.net/RedBreast/kLvsg302/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

* { /*Or at least html, body and #messages*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#messages{
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding:20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:25%;
    background:#fff;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vimxts/pm5wkgv4/2/

Also, you should only have one id in a page, you may delete the `div` part before `#message`

Comment: It doesn't work. Now both the div and the entire page are scrollable. Can I somehow disable the option to be able to scroll the page?

Comment: @aCodingN00b can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @aCodingN00b how about now?

Comment: Still, both the page and the div are scrollable.

Comment: It works now, after I changed the height of the body and html to 90% instead of 100% . When It was at 100%, the page was scrollable even without anything at the bottom of it. I don't know why, though I am still unsure of how this will look on other screen sizes.

Comment: @aCodingN00b That's only a trick, it won't work in some condition. I've found a solution with some changes

Comment: What's the solution then? Thanks.

Comment: @aCodingN00b Please see my new answer

Answer (score 1):

Would this be a solution to your problem: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GK7Pd1y7hqKROBsghTgN)

you can use

```
height:60vh;
```

to specify the heigt.

Comment: Using percentages against pixels is not wise. You will find it not satisfy in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using Daniel Cheung answer, if you want the page to be unscrollable, you might want to add : `overflow: hidden`.

https://jsfiddle.net/pm5wkgv4/1/

```
#message {
    max-height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It would cause some elements to disappear because of the `margin`, `padding` and `box-sizing`